# mongo-express doesn't use custom password defined in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I am trying to change the login-password for the mongo-express Web-UI. I set `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD` and `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME` but still only "admin:pass" works in the browser. Why aren't the values of `docker-compose.yaml` taken?

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
    networks:
      - mongo-db-net

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: rootpw
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:rootpw@mongo:27017/
    networks:
      - mongo-db-net


networks:
  mongo-db-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME` and `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD` options relate to the database, not the web interface. To configure the web login, use options `ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME` and `ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD`

Explanations for mongo-express environmental variables can be found at [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express) under the 'Configuration' section